# How to edit image field output from template

Tags: entities, theming

My goal is to edit the output of a specific field in a view.

There is an image field, and I would like to specify how it is output. So that instead of

```
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://url.com/sites/default/files/styles/com_home_news/public/field/image/myimage.jpg?itok=8e4_c1xI" width="290" height="140" alt="">
```

I can output something like

```
<img src="imagepath/image.jpg">
```

I'd like to be able to edit the output freely and just have access to the image path for this specific view.

I am currently editing

```
views-view-field--com-retheme-home-news--field-image.tpl.php
```

However I'm not sure how to actually access the path to the image. Using

```
<?php print $output; ?>
```

Only prints out what it would have before.

I understand that I could change the field itself to only present the path, however that isn't an option since there is already a lot of content taking advantage of how the field is already setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of a work around but I found a solution. What I ended up doing was use a regular expression on $output to grab the path and then used it to spit out what I wanted like so:

```
$pattern = '/src\s*=\s*"(.+?)"/';
$img = preg_match($pattern,$output,$results);
print "<img ".$results[0].">";
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module

Then in your view, click on your image field and select url as the formatter, so it prints the url rather than the image.

[image]

**Option A)** In the rewrite results field, use the token for your image field.

Example: `<img src="[field_image]" class="yay-we-did-it">`

**Option B)** if you want to use the .tpl.php file, put this inside it.

`<img src='<?php print $fields["field_image"]->content; ?>' class='yay-we-did-it'>`

Comment: This won't work in my scenario since I already have a large number of nodes that already have the image attached to the image field. My solution needs to make use of the content that is already present rather than adding more images to the new field on each previous node. My solution above grabs the URL as intended.

Comment: @Matt, you don't need to add more images. This module grabs the urls of the images.

Comment: But I have other subdomains using different themes that need to use images without the image url. Wouldn't that break everything using the other theme?

Comment: nope, all this does is print/output the url rather than the image itself. **In your view** you get to choose weather you want the image or the url.